# SQLFORM grid css

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, grid, web2py

My SQLFORM.grid looks terrible. I am using bootstrap and I would like to know how to set class  and everything else that needs to be set for my web2py form to correct it so it will look ok?

this is my html

```
<div>
<div id="mainContainer" >
    <h4><b>{{=T('Šifrant delavcev')}}</b></h4>
    <div id="SifrantDelavcev">
        {{=form}}
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Bootstrap 2, be sure to include [web2py.css](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/static/css/web2py.css) and [web2py_bootstrap.css](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/static/css/web2py_bootstrap.css).

If using Bootstrap 3, you may need to do some of your own customizing.